# Define incomplete Record, while retaining the constraints on mapped type

Tags: typescript

Say I have an interface `S`:

```js
interface S {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: string;
}
```

I want to create an incomplete mapping from `S` to some other `AllowedMappedType` type:

```js
type AllowedMappedType = "red" | "green" | "blue";
const map: Record<keyof S, AllowedMappedType> = {
  a: "red",
  c: "green",
};
```

This doesn't work, because we don't define a mapping for all keys of `S`. You could avoid this by getting rid of type specialization:

```js
const map = {
  a: "red",
  c: "green",
}; // map has a type of { a: string, c: string }, i.e. we lose the constraint on AllowedMappedType
```

But I want to retain the `AllowedMappedType` constraint. `Partial` doesn't work for me either because I want the type to not have optional properties.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

How about Pick?

```js
interface S {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: string;
  }
type AllowedMappedType = "red" | "green" | "blue";
const map: Pick<Record<keyof S, AllowedMappedType>, 'a' | 'c'> = {
  a: "red",
  c: "green",
};
```

Or Omit:

```js
const map: Omit<Record<keyof S, AllowedMappedType>, 'b'> = {
    a: "red",
    c: "green",
};
```